# prevent mmenu close on click on page

Tags: mmenu

I have one mmenu instance. The default behaviour is that it closes when I click outside of the menu. How can I prevent this behaviour? To force the menu closure I want to use only a predisposed button (already working)

------------------ ADD Some details --------

My mmenu instance is as below

```
<nav id="listPanel">
            <ul>
                <li id="closeButtonLi"><span id="panelButtonClose" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> Chiudi</span></li>
                <!--<li style="padding:10px"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Aggiungi atleta"></li>-->
                <li id="athSelectorLi" style="padding:10px">
                    <input id="athSelector" style="width:70%;"/>
                    <img id="plusButton" style="width:35px;height:auto;cursor:pointer;margin-left:12px;" src="../../../docsUI/images/common/add.png"/>
                    <img id="removeButton" style="width:35px;height:auto;cursor:pointer;margin-left:7px;" src="../../../docsUI/images/common/remove.png"/>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <table id="athTable" class="hover compact" width="95%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>markerColor</th>
                                <th>bib</th>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <th>avgSpeed</th>
                                <th>locate</th>
                                <th>remove</th>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>  



     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#listPanel").mmenu({
        "classes": "mm-light",
        "offCanvas": {
              "zposition": "front",
              "position": "right"
               }
        }
        });  

        $("#panelButton").click(function() {
             $("#listPanel").trigger("open.mm");
              });
        $("#panelButtonClose").click(function() {
             $("#listPanel").trigger("close.mm");
              });
        });
```

What I need is to  close the #listPanel menu only using the close button

```
<li id="closeButtonLi"><span id="panelButtonClose" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> Chiudi</span></li>
```

With current implementation, the button works as expected, but the menu closes also when I click outside the menu in the remaining part of the page. I want to avoid exactly it (close the menu clicking on the page as is the default behaviour as described in http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial/open-and-close-the-menu.html)

I searched both on Stack Overflow current answers and on website documentation, but I did not find any solution. The only API present is the onClick but it is  not relevant for my needs.

Comment: That's apparently not built into the api as an option, which means you'd need to extend the plugin. That's beyond the scope of what's reasonable considering you haven't shown any attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mm-blocker').unbind('mousedown')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove div which will prevent close mmenu

```
$('#mm-blocker').remove();
```

better than unbind mousedown